# spaCy: optimizing tokenization

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I'm currently trying to tokenize a text file where each line is the body text of a tweet:

```
"According to data reported to FINRA, short volume percent for $SALT clocked in at 39.19% on 12-29-17 http://www.volumebot.com/?s=SALT"
"@Good2go @krueb The chart I posted definitely supports ng going lower.  Gobstopper&#39; 2.12, might even be conservative."
"@Crypt0Fortune Its not dumping as bad as it used to...."
"$XVG.X LOL. Someone just triggered a cascade of stop-loss orders and scooped up morons&#39; coins. Oldest trick in the stock trader&#39;s book."
```

The file is 59,397 lines long (a day's worth of data) and I'm using spaCy for pre-processing/tokenization. It's currently taking me around 8.5 minutes and I was wondering if there were any way of optimising the following code to be quicker as 8.5 minutes seems awfully long for this process:

```
def token_loop(path):
    store = []
    files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]

    start_time = time.monotonic()
    for filename in files:
        with open("./data/"+filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                tokens = nlp(line.lower())
                tokens = [token.lemma_ for token in tokens if not token.orth_.isspace() and token.is_alpha and not token.is_stop and len(token.orth_) != 1]
                store.append(tokens)

    end_time = time.monotonic()
    print("Time taken to tokenize:",timedelta(seconds=end_time - start_time))

    return store
```

Although it says files, it's currently only looping over 1 file.

Just to note, I only need this to tokenize the content; I don't need any extra tagging etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't optimised the pipeline yet.  You'll get a significant speed up from disabling the pipeline components you don't need, like so:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'tagger', 'ner'])
```

This should get you down to about the two-minute mark, or better, on its own.

If you need a further speed up, you can look at multi-threading using `nlp.pipe`.  Docs for multi-threading are here:
https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#section-multithreading

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. Just to get a better understanding, say my use case is to tokenize these lines prior to putting the tokens through word2vec. Do I need POS tagging, named entity or the parser at all? I had plotted the results of each on a PCA graph and they tend to differ quite a bit (new to all this so couldn't make much sense of it!), would these extra options be unnecessary to create word embeddings?

Comment: They would be unnecessary.  But Spacy does have vector representations built in (except the small models – see the models docs here: https://spacy.io/usage/models.)

What's your goal?

Comment: Very early stages of building a Twitter content recommender system using own data, so far all I've done is created a word2vec model based on these tokens and I've to look into RNNs at some point. No background in ML so it's all a little confusing for now.

Comment: OK, I see – sounds like a good project!  There are a lot of different ways you could tackle that.  Sticking with Spacy, you could look at vector similarities: https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#vectors-similarity.  Also, you've probably come across it already, but Gensim (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) is a great library for topic modelling, document/text similarity etc.  Definitely worth checking out.

Comment: Why not `nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'tagger', 'ner', 'entity_ruler'])`?
He only want to tokenize, so he doesn't need the entity ruler as well

Comment: @Green a very reasonable question.  The difference is because 'entity_ruler' isn't enabled by default.  Create an nlp object, `nlp = spacy.load("en")` and then check the pipeline, `print(nlp.pipeline)` and you'll see only `parser`, `tagger` and `ner` are enabled by default.  You could argue it's more thorough to disable `entity_ruler` too, but by that logic you should also disable `textcat`, `sentencizer`, `merge_noun_chunks` etc., and then you're into a lot of typing which has no impact on speed and, in my opinion, reduces the clarity of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nlp.pipe(all_lines)` instead of nlp(line) for a faster processing

see Spacy's documentation - https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines